# Looking for a Basic Lego set with mostly large bricks

Tags: shopping

I am looking to buy my son his first set of LEGO bricks (because my mom will not give me my old ones!!!). Most of the 650ish piece sets I have looked at contain a large amount of 1x2, 2x2, etc. I am looking for a set that has more 2x4s, 2x6s or bigger than those with more smaller pieces. Can anyone recommend a good set? It does not need to be that big of a set either, but if I could find one that would be great!! I cannot wait to finally own my own LEGO bricks that don't actually belong to my parents!!!

Comment: Most Lego kits have small parts. How old is your son? If he's old enough not to put the pieces in his mouth, just get a basic bricks set. He'll grow into the tiny pieces soon enough. He'll be 4 or 5 before you know it.

Comment: I don't think 2x6 bricks were ever common.

Answer (score 2):

If you can get to a Lego shop, there is a Pick a Brick wall with mostly large bricks that you buy by the cupful for less per brick than you would pay in most sets.

These two sites:

http://www.brickbuildr.com/view/pab/

, and

http://wallofbricks.com/

show you the current(ish) contents of the Pick a Brick walls around the world, they are updated by fans so they might not be up to date.

Answer (score 1):

There are always a range of bricks-only sets in production, the current one is called [LEGO Basic Bricks Deluxe](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/LEGO-Basic-Bricks-Deluxe-6177) ([Inventory](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=6177-1)). That is probably the closest you will get to what you want at this moment (November 2014).

With Christmas coming up, though, keep an eye out for a new brick set from a major retailer like Walmart. In the past there have been gems like [LEGO 5512 XXL Brick Box](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=5512-1).

Your best bet, however, is to go to [Bricklink.com](http://www.bricklink.com/) and find a store that sells ample quantities of used bricks in the colors and sizes you want.

Comment: isn't this exactly what the question was trying to avoid - most of the bricks in that set are 2x2 or smaller

Comment: I guess so. My point is that it's the closest to what he is looking for.